How does the cohomology theory on de Rham (pre)stack compute de Rham cohomology?
Recently when I'm reading PTVV, Shifted Symplectic Structures, in Sec. 2.1 Mapping stacks, the authors use the identification $H^*(X,E)\simeq H^{*}_{dR}(Y/k,\mathcal{E})$ to show $X=Y_{dR}$ admits an orientation. I try to prove this equivalence but something gets wrong.
For simplicity we just suppose $Y$ is a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is only the usual $D_{Y/k}$-module locally free oover $Y$ which corresponds to $E\in \mathbf{QCoh}(Y_{dR})$. Now $X=Y_{dR}$ is the (derived) de Rham (pre)stack such that for a cdga $A$, $X(A)=Y(H^0(A)^{red})$. So the identification above means the inner hom complex $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{QCoh}(Y_{dR})}(\mathcal{O},E)$ computes the de Rham cohomology of $Y$.
Then in arXiv:1111.2087, it's shown there is an equivalence $\mathbf{QCoh}(Y_{dR})\simeq \mathbf{DMod}(Y)$. So we will have
$$\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{QCoh}(Y_{dR})}(\mathcal{O},E)\simeq\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{DMod}(Y)}(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{E})$$
To compute the right side, we use Lemma 1.5.27 in the book HTT which says we have resolutions
\begin{align*}
& 0\rightarrow D_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \bigwedge^d T_Y\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow D_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\bigwedge^0T_Y\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow 0\\
& 0\rightarrow \Omega^{0}_{Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}D_Y\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow \Omega^{d}_{Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}D_Y\rightarrow \omega_Y\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
where $T_Y$ is the tangent complex and $\omega_Y$ is the canonical bundle. Then from Prop. 2.6.14 in HTT, we have
$$\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{DMod}(Y)}(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{E})\simeq \omega_{Y}\otimes_{D_Y}^{\mathbb{L}}\mathcal{E}[-d]$$
which will actually be the complex
$$0\rightarrow \Omega^{0}_{X}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow \Omega_{Y}^d\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal{E}\rightarrow 0$$
by taking global sections.
So here we can see $H^n(X,E)$ is trivial for $n> d$. But $H^*_{dR}(Y,\mathcal{E})$ is in fact the hypercpohomology of the complex above which should be the cohomology of the total complex when taking injective resolutions, so that it has the top degree $2d$.
I think my arguments must be something wrong, but I do not know where it's.

$H^n(X,E)$ is not trivial for $n > d$. The de Rham cohomology $H^*_{dR}(Y,\mathcal{E})$ is indeed computed by this twisted de Rham complex $\Omega^\bullet \otimes \mathcal{E}$, whose cohomology sheaves vanish in degrees above $d$. To get the de Rham cohomology, you must take the derived global sections of this complex, which has amplitude contained in $[0,d+d]$. The first $d$ is the length of the complex, the second $d$ is the dimension of the variety.

@JoshuaMundinger I know where my problem is! Thank you very much!
